# OpenCart the same variable doesn't work on different templates

Tags: php, opencart

I'm making an OpenCart theme but it won't work in some way.
In the head.tpl I use a variable called $store, and in theme 1 (the old theme) it works, but in theme 2 (the new one I'm making) it doesn't and I get errors that it doesn't exists:

> Notice: Undefined variable: stores in /home/website/domains/website.be/public_html/update/catalog/view/theme/webtheme/template/common/header.tpl on line 41

This is all made on the same site on with the same database etc. I'm just changing the settings in the admin panel to test my template.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

The notice says it is undefined in `footer.tpl`, not `head.tpl`. Check if you have uploaded `footer.php` to your controller.

Comment: I'm sorry, I used a wrong example. The right example should be this one: $store, when I use it in the new theme, I get errors like Notice: Undefined variable: stores in /home/websites/domains/website.be/public_html/update/catalog/view/theme/webtheme/template/common/header.tpl on line 41

Answer (score 0):

Normally in opencart using the variable from default theme to newly created theme is possible but make sure that all the variable you defined in home.php and header.php (Controller) and language

Answer (score 0):

I found it guys!
The error didn't came from these variables but from $output['description'] in the footer and sidebar.
Thanks anyway!